# Breaking down a cell

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell (47,1), where each element is itself a cell (12,1), and each of those 12 cells contains a double (31,1). This means I have 17484 values. How can I extract all those values into one cell (17484,1)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a nested array of cells (`47 x 1`) where each cell is another `12 x 1` cell and each cell is a `31 x 1` array.... that's a pretty awful way to store data... but let's go with the flow.

The command you'd enter in MATLAB is, assuming your matrix is stored in `A`:

```
B = reshape(cell2mat(cellfun(@cell2mat, A, 'uni', 0)), 1, []);
```

Let's break this up step-by-step and explain as we go:

1. `cellfun(@cell2mat, A, 'uni', 0)`

   [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) is a function that iterates over all cells in a cell array and applies a function to it.  Each cell in `A` would be a 12 x 1 cell array where each cell is a 31 x 1 matrix.  In our case, we use the function [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to take all of these cells that are 31 x 1 matrices and concatenate them into a 31 x 12 matrix.  The `uni=0` flag means that the output of `cellfun` is not a uniform numeric matrix.  Instead, the output of `cellfun` will be a 47 cell array where each cell element is a 31 x 12 matrix.
2. `cell2mat(...#1...)`

   This concatenates all of the 31 x 12 matrices together so that we get a 31 x 564 matrix as the output from step #1 is another cell array.
3. `B = reshape(...#2..., [], 1);`

   The final step is to take this matrix and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the matrix into a single vector of size 17484 x 1.  This takes each column of the intermediate matrix in step #2 and places them all into a single vector.  `B` contains this output vector.

---

If for some reason you want to place each element into an individual cell, you can use the undocumented function [`sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) to take each element in the output `B` and put them into individual cells:

```
Bcell = sprintfc('%f', B);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you can change the data structure, change it to a 47 by 12 by 31 double. Doing so one of the many advantages is that you probably don't need to do this conversion at all and use linear indices.

```
%some example data
X=rand(4,5,6)
%3d indexing
X(1,2,3)
%linear indexing
X(3)
%Converting to 1-d:
X=X(:)
```

If you want to stick with your data structure, you can use `X=[X{:}]`. Each call of this code merges the two outer levels of your data structure to one cell, thus you have to call it twice.

```
X=[X{:}]
X=[X{:}]
%There are only very few cases, where numeric data should be stored in a cell. Conciser removing the last line to get a vector.
X=num2cell(X)
```